# Firebase Messaging SERIVER_NOT_AVILABLE

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When app opens user should subscribe to a topic to receive any updates with notification
the problem is sometimes it subscribe successfully and sometimes it gives me error [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  lifeCycleHandler();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
   
    ...

    await ini(context);

  });
}

Future<void> ini(BuildContext context) async {
   ...

   
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic).whenComplete(() {
       debugPrint('successfully subscribed to $topic');
    },).onError((error, stackTrace) {
       debugPrint('an error occurred while subscribing to topic $topic \n $stackTrace \n error $error');
},);

   
}
```

The issue is sometimes it subscribes and sometimes it gives me this error

> E/flutter (17003): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
> E/flutter (17003): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
> E/flutter (17003): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
> E/flutter (17003): 
> E/flutter (17003): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:518:43)
> E/flutter (17003): 
> E/flutter (17003): #3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.deleteToken (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:192:7)
> E/flutter (17003): 
> E/flutter (17003): #4      MyMenuState.initToken (package:buffet/Screens/menu.dart:3250:5)
> E/flutter (17003): 
> E/flutter (17003): #5      MyMenuState.ini (package:buffet/Screens/menu.dart:1682:5)
> E/flutter (17003): 
> E/flutter (17003): #6      MyMenuState.initState. (package:buffet/Screens/menu.dart:132:7)
> E/flutter (17003): 
> E/flutter (17003):

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Usually, this is caused if Google Play services is not installed on the phone or it's in an extremely bad state. Make sure that Google Play services is installed.

If the issue persists, I would recommend reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they can offer personalized help. It’ll be challenging to troubleshoot this error on a public forum without extensively discussing certain details. Best if you can provide a bug report as it's a good starting point to investigate.